# Can't import to Unity video clip rendered using FFmpeg for Unity

Tags: ffmpeg, unity

I am using FFmpeg to render a video in Unity. For the FFmpegCaptureCommand.OutputOptions I'm using this command:

```
-g 24 -c:v h264 -preset medium -crf 32 -pix_fmt yuv420p -color_primaries bt709 -color_trc bt709 -colorspace bt709 -color_range pc -f mov -movflags frag_keyframe+empty_moov -vf setpts=2*PTS
```

The video output plays fine on windows media player or VLC but when I try to import the clip into Unity I get the following error:

```
WindowsVideoMedia error 0xc00d36e6 while reading C:/.../d.mov

Context: Getting duration.
Error details: The requested attribute was not found.
Track types:
   Video Track [1024 x 1024], type: H264
```

I can create a working copy of the video with this command:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mov output.mov
```

I assume ffmpeg creates a new container for the video when it copies it but I can't figure out why is not doing it in the first place.

Using ffprobe

```
ffprobe -show_streams -select_streams v C:\...\d.mov
```

I get this info on the original video:

```
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'C:\...\d.mov':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : qt
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: qt
    encoder         : Lavf59.4.101
  Duration: 00:00:02.97, start: 0.066667, bitrate: 2471 kb/s
  Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuvj420p(pc, bt709), 1024x1024, 2465 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 15360 tbn (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
      vendor_id       : FFMP
      encoder         : Lavc59.4.100 libx264
[STREAM]
index=0
codec_name=h264
codec_long_name=H.264 / AVC / MPEG-4 AVC / MPEG-4 part 10
profile=High
codec_type=video
codec_tag_string=avc1
codec_tag=0x31637661
width=1024
height=1024
coded_width=1024
coded_height=1024
closed_captions=0
has_b_frames=2
sample_aspect_ratio=N/A
display_aspect_ratio=N/A
pix_fmt=yuvj420p
level=32
color_range=pc
color_space=bt709
color_transfer=bt709
color_primaries=bt709
chroma_location=left
field_order=unknown
refs=1
is_avc=true
nal_length_size=4
id=N/A
r_frame_rate=30/1
avg_frame_rate=30/1
time_base=1/15360
start_pts=1024
start_time=0.066667
duration_ts=45568
duration=2.966667
bit_rate=2465649
max_bit_rate=N/A
bits_per_raw_sample=8
nb_frames=N/A
nb_read_frames=N/A
nb_read_packets=N/A
DISPOSITION:default=1
DISPOSITION:dub=0
DISPOSITION:original=0
DISPOSITION:comment=0
DISPOSITION:lyrics=0
DISPOSITION:karaoke=0
DISPOSITION:forced=0
DISPOSITION:hearing_impaired=0
DISPOSITION:visual_impaired=0
DISPOSITION:clean_effects=0
DISPOSITION:attached_pic=0
DISPOSITION:timed_thumbnails=0
DISPOSITION:captions=0
DISPOSITION:descriptions=0
DISPOSITION:metadata=0
DISPOSITION:dependent=0
DISPOSITION:still_image=0
TAG:handler_name=VideoHandler
TAG:vendor_id=FFMP
TAG:encoder=Lavc59.4.100 libx264
[/STREAM]
```

and this on the copied video:

```
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'C:\...\d1.mov':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : qt
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: qt
    encoder         : Lavf59.4.101
  Duration: 00:00:02.97, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 2869 kb/s
  Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuvj420p(pc, bt709), 1024x1024, 2865 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 15360 tbn (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
      vendor_id       : FFMP
      encoder         : Lavc59.4.100 libx264
[STREAM]
index=0
codec_name=h264
codec_long_name=H.264 / AVC / MPEG-4 AVC / MPEG-4 part 10
profile=High
codec_type=video
codec_tag_string=avc1
codec_tag=0x31637661
width=1024
height=1024
coded_width=1024
coded_height=1024
closed_captions=0
has_b_frames=2
sample_aspect_ratio=N/A
display_aspect_ratio=N/A
pix_fmt=yuvj420p
level=32
color_range=pc
color_space=bt709
color_transfer=bt709
color_primaries=bt709
chroma_location=left
field_order=unknown
refs=1
is_avc=true
nal_length_size=4
id=N/A
r_frame_rate=30/1
avg_frame_rate=30/1
time_base=1/15360
start_pts=0
start_time=0.000000
duration_ts=45568
duration=2.966667
bit_rate=2865152
max_bit_rate=N/A
bits_per_raw_sample=8
nb_frames=89
nb_read_frames=N/A
nb_read_packets=N/A
DISPOSITION:default=1
DISPOSITION:dub=0
DISPOSITION:original=0
DISPOSITION:comment=0
DISPOSITION:lyrics=0
DISPOSITION:karaoke=0
DISPOSITION:forced=0
DISPOSITION:hearing_impaired=0
DISPOSITION:visual_impaired=0
DISPOSITION:clean_effects=0
DISPOSITION:attached_pic=0
DISPOSITION:timed_thumbnails=0
DISPOSITION:captions=0
DISPOSITION:descriptions=0
DISPOSITION:metadata=0
DISPOSITION:dependent=0
DISPOSITION:still_image=0
TAG:handler_name=VideoHandler
TAG:vendor_id=FFMP
TAG:encoder=Lavc59.4.100 libx264
[/STREAM]
```

I noticed the `start_time` is 0.000000 on the copied video but the original is 0.066667, I wonder if that has anything to do with it.

If I look at the video properties/details the "Length" attribute is missing on the original video but exists in the copy. Does Unity need that info maybe?

What am I missing here? How could I make my original command output a video with the proper data that Unity needs for importing it?.

Thanks in advance.